# Powershell failing to attach SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, powershell

As part of my automation process I need to attach some dirty databases. I say dirty because they are from a point-in-time snapshot of a disk volume. When the snapshot was taken the DB was still actively being written from.

There are two databases. The mdf size for databaseA is 131GB. The mdf size for databaseB is 3.4GB.

I have tried two different methods to attach the databases with Powershell.

The first is using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` and the second is using a SQL SMO object and calling `AttachDatabase`.

Both methods work successfully for databaseB but fail for databaseA.

The error message I get sucks...

> Exception calling "AttachDatabase" with "4" argument(s): "Attach database failed for Server 'DB01'. "
>   At line:17 char:1
>   + $srv.AttachDatabase("databaseA", $dbfiles, "sa", "None")
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException

If I go in to SQL Server Management Studio instead of running the script and just right click and attach DB that way, the database will attach without issue in about 20 to 30 seconds.

I'm confused as to why Management Studio works and my script doesn't. It's also annoying that the script doesn't provide a better error message.

Has any one else encountered this issue or have any idea how i can get some better error feedback?

Comment: Does your powershell command fail for just these dbs, or any/all dbs?  I suggest retrying your command and capture a profiler trace to see if it's even hitting the server, and what values are being executed.  It would also help if you posted your exact powershell command.

Comment: It's just the big one that fails.

Comment: ok, and what did you find when you ran profiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a purely timeout issue.

When I ran Invoke-Sqlcmd  with a -Timeout value of 0 things started working.

I am unsure exactly as to why Management Studio can attach the db in about 5 mins but it takes much, much longer when using Invoke-Sqlcmd. Nonetheless, it works.